# Finding the centre of a circle drawn using leaflet draw and also calculating the distance between 2 lat longs

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-draw

Am new to JS so the below queries may look simple.

Query: I have drawn multiple circles on the map and i need to fetch all the markers details available with in the circle.

In order to achieve that I am trying to fetch the centre of a circle in lat long and calculating the distance of all markers on the map from that centre of circle. If (distance <= radius) concluding the marker is with in the circle.

How is the centre of the circle determined?

How is the distance calculated between the centre and the marker?

Answer (score 2):

You first loop through the circles then something like this should work.

```
ver theRadius = thecircle.getRadius();  //in Meters
var theExtent = thecircle.getBounds();
var theCenterPt = theExtent.getCenter();
var insidePts ={};

   // Loop through each point in GeoJSON file

thePoints.eachLayer(function (layer) {

    // Lat, long of current point
    layer_lat_long = layer.getLatLng();
    // Distance from our circle marker To current point in meters
    distance_from_centerPoint = layer_lat_long.distanceTo(theCenterPt);
    // See if meters is within radius
    if (distance_from_centerPoint <= theRadius) {
        counter_points_in_circle += 1;

         insidePts.push(layer.feature);  //array of point within circle
    }

});
console.log(insidePts.length);   
console.log("results "+JSON.stringify(insidePts));
```